# MVVM Light: How to get data from usercontrols?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a class MyDataCollection that contains MyMetaData and MyData. In my application i have two usercontrolls that display input fields to the user. One for the MyMetaData and the other for MyData. Both usercontrols are included in the MainPage.

My Question is: How should i get the data from the usercontrols then the user klicks on the save-button (located on the mainpage)?

**Update**
I have changed my code accordingly to blindmeis post but now the MetaDataView is not shown:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MetaDataTemplate">
        <view:MetaDataView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MetaDataTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: the content have to be your viewmodel object, e.g. MyMetaData. i dont have silverlight but like rachel said, you can try to set the ContentTemplate to your datatemplate. see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not doing mvvm the easy way?(viewmodel first). you say you have a mainpage - this means you also have a mainpageviewmodel. your mainpageviewmodel handles at least the save command. now you want to show MyMetaData and MyData on your mainpage. so the easy way would be to create one MyMetaData instance and one MyData instance in your mainviewmodel.

```
public class MainPageViewmodel
{
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    public MyDataViewmodel MyData { get; set; }
    public MyMetaDataViewmodel MyMetaData { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewmodel()
    {
        this.MyData = new MyDataViewmodel();
        this.MyMetaData = new MyMetaDataViewmodel();
    }

}

public class MyDataViewmodel
{}

public class MyMetaDataViewmodel
{}
```

your mainpage just need 2 datatemplates and 2 contentpresenter.

//resources

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Local:MyDataViewmodel}">
        <view:MyDataUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Local:MyMetaDataViewmodel}">
        <view:MyMetaDataUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyData}" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyMetaData}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

because your mainpageviewmodel has both "child" viewmodel, you have all information you want on your savecommand.

if you have another scenario pls update your question, maybe post some code.

EDIT: i have no silverlight so that just a suggestion: maybe rachel can give you a better answer.

```
<Grid>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyMetaData}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MetaDataTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

if silverlight cant handle datatemplates with datatype you could just put the usercontrol there directly.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <view:MyDataUserControl DataContext="{Binding MyData}" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <view:MyMetaDataUserControl DataContext="{Binding MyMetaData}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: They're probably coming from a WinForms background, or there's some tutorial out there that teaches View-First :)

Comment: I tried your code but i think DataType is not supported in DataTemplate (Silverlight).

Comment: @jwillmer That's correct, implicit `DataTemplates` are not supported in Silverlight (yet). Instead, give your `DataTemplates` an `x:Key` property, and set the `ContentTemplate` of your `ContentControls` to whatever `DataTemplate` they should use to draw the object

Comment: @jwillmer, i missed your silverlight tag sorry for that.

Comment: @ blindmeis no problem but could you update your code? i tried to fix it with @Rachel comment but it didn't work (see my update).

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this question as `MVVM`, your ViewModels should contain both your `SaveCommand` and all the data needed to perform the actual save

Your `MainViewModel` should contain `MyMetaData` and `MyData` properties (which are bound to their respective `UserControls`), and each of those objects should contain properties for any data needed in the `UserControl`. For example, if your `UserControl` had a `TextBox` for `Name`, then your data object should have a property for the `Name` that the `TextBox` binds to.

If the Save button is located in one of those `UserControls` then the respective ViewModel should have a `SaveCommand` that gets executed when the `Button` is clicked. All the data needed for the `Save` is also located in that ViewModel, so you're good to go.

If your `MainViewModel` is in charge of saving the data, then it should be able to hook into your sub ViewModel's `SaveCommand` and attach it's own method, such as

```
this.MyData.SaveCommand = this.SaveCommand();
```

and all the data needed for the save can be found in `this.MyData`

If the `SaveButton` is located in your `MainView`, and not in one of the UserControls, then the SaveCommand should be part of `MainViewModel`, and all the data needed for the save can be found in `this.MyData` or `This.MyMetaData`.

Remember, with MVVM your ViewModels are your application. The View is just a pretty interface that allows users to interact with your ViewModels.

Comment: +1 for writing what i think all the time :) "Remember, with MVVM your ViewModels are your application. The View is just a pretty interface that allows users to interact with your ViewModels."

Answer (score 1):

You should use Two-way bindings to automatically update the value in your controller. Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Here's an example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyMetaData, Mode=TwoWay }" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyData, Mode=TwoWay }" />
```

Comment: I do it like this but how can i get the data from the usercontrol-viewmodel into the mainpage-viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a little sample, how you can use the MVVM Light Messenger for ViewModel-to-ViewModel communication. Say you have an MyDataCollection class:

```
public class MyDataCollection
{
    public int MyData;
    public string MyMetaData;
}
```

On your MainViewModel you have a RelayCommand (from MVVM light toolkit) binded by your View's SaveButton. When the Connad is executed, you will have to send a Message with a callback action to request data from the subcriber. The callback takes MyDataCollection as parameter:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

    //Ctor
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessageAction<MyDataCollection>>(
                    new NotificationMessageAction<MyDataCollection>("SaveData", SaveCallback)));
    }

    private void SaveCallback(MyDataCollection dataCollection)
    {
        // process your dataCollection... 
    }
}
```

The UserControlViewModel has properties the InputTextBoxes are binded too. It just has to register to the message and call the callback with data properties:

```
public class UserControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //Properties
    public string UserControlMetaData { get; set; }
    public int UserControlData { get; set; }

    //Ctor
    public UserControlViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessageAction<MyDataCollection>>(this, MessageReceived);
    }

    // private Method to handle all kinds of messages.
    private void MessageReceived(MessageBase msg)
    {
        if(msg is NotificationMessageAction<MyDataCollection>)
        {
            var actionMsg = msg as NotificationMessageAction<MyDataCollection>;
            if(actionMsg.Notification == "SaveData")  // Is this the Message, we are looking for?
            {
                // here the MainViewModels callback is called.
                actionMsg.Execute(new MyDataCollection() {MyData = UserControlData, MyMetaData = UserControlMetaData});
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use messengers or you will have to set the properties over the ViewModelLocator

Messenger example of how I use it to set the UI language
ViewModel A, I register a listener here with the "SetLanguage" token:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "SetLanguage", false, input =>
{
    SetLanguage(input);
});
```

ViewModel B, here I send the message with the "SetLanguage" token:

```
Messenger.Default.Send("en-EN", "SetLanguage");
```

---

ViewModelLocator example in ViewModel A, I access data in ViewModel B over the locator:

```
short value = 12;
var myFilteredDataList = ViewModelLocator.ViewModelBStatic.MyDataList.Any(m => m.code == value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions now:

View:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyMetaDataView}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public MetaDataViewModel MyMetaDataViewModel { get; set; }
public MetaDataView MyMetaDataView { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    MyMetaDataViewModel = new MetaDataViewModel();
    MyMetaDataView = new MetaDataView();

    MyMetaDataView.DataContext = MyMetaDataViewModel;
}
```

or ----

View:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  x:Key="MetaDataViewTemplate">
        <view:MetaDataView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyMetaDataViewModel}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MetaDataViewTemplate}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public MetaDataViewModel MyMetaDataViewModel { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    MyMetaDataViewModel = new MetaDataViewModel();
}
```

Comment: the first one break mvvm cause MetaDataView is an UserControl or?

Comment: @blindmeis you are right, because it breaks mvvm i have implemented the second solution ;-)